# How to make two asp.net web applications have the same domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and am trying to work on an application that uses another separate child application. I need to know how do I configure the application domains for the 2 apps to be same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the domain name?  That's more of an IIS (web server) concern than an ASP.NET concern.  Essentially one or more application would be in a "virtual directory" in the IIS website for that domain name.

Comment: Bind "Default Web Site" to `domain.com` (if you're not using HTTPS you have even less work to do...) and then deploy each application to different subfolders/applications (`a` and `b`, for the sake of an example) and bam! `domain.com/a` and `domain.com/b`.

Answer (score 2):

Use  [virtual directory](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) in iis.

> In IIS, you can create sites, applications, and virtual directories to
>   share information with users over the Internet, an intranet, or an
>   extranet. Although these concepts existed in earlier versions of IIS,
>   several changes in IIS 7 and above affect the definition and
>   functionality of these concepts. Most importantly, sites,
>   applications, and virtual directories now work together in a
>   hierarchical relationship as the basic building blocks for hosting
>   online content and providing online services.